# Split Android layout with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, rotation

I want to diplay this layout: Two fragments, the first one turned by 90 degrees counter-clockwise (well the layout of it) stuck to the left side of the screen and the second one filling the remaining space on the right side of it.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: This is what I want to achieve.]

I use this layout to display them floating the one over the other:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp"
tools:context=".StartActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is that I don't manage to rotate the fragment and still ensure that the fragment's layout is anlingnt correctly while supporting API level 11+

Comment: And what is the problem? The rotation? I think rotating views/layouts/fragments in Android is not very easy.

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg I edited the question.